# Anchoring Across Different Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, anchor

So right now I have a script that allows anchoring, but it only works within the page I am currently on.

```
    $('.menu a').click(function(){
        var question = this.innerHTML;
        var answer = $.find('dt:contains(' + question + ')');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(answer).offset().top
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });

  <div class="menu">
        <div>
            <h3 class="heading"><a href="/about">About</a> <span class="expand">+</span></h3>
            <ul class="subheader">
                <li><a href="/about">How Can You Help?</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">How can I submit a show?</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">Who are we?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 class="heading"><a id="contact" href="contact">Contact</a> <span class="expand">+</span></h3>
            <ul class="subheader">
                <li><a href="contact">Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact">On Site</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact">Social Media</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to alter my current script so that I can anchor myself to the correct position on the next page.

For example, I am currently on my About page, but I click on "Email" in my menu. What I want to happen is for the page to redirect itself to the Contact page their anchor itself to where Email is. Right now, it just puts me on the top of the page.

I'm trying not to do this with several id's because these aren't my only pages so it would not be the best idea to have over 30 id's just to get this to work. I guess that's my last resort though.

Comment: can you use the `#` character in the `href` URL?

Comment: @akonsu It depends. Do you mean having only the # character in the href URL or adding that on to my href URL? If you meant the latter, then yes I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't clear, but I assume you have a javascript function that takes a string and finds the correct place to send the user. In that case, you can run this on page-load with the page's current hash:

```
$(function() {
    if (location.hash) {
        var question = location.hash;
        var answer = $.find('dt:contains(' + question + ')');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(answer).offset().top
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

And your email link can look like this:

```
<li><a href="contact#email">Email</a></li>
```

Or, if you want to use the `<a>` content as the hash:

```
<li><a href="contact">Email</a></li>
...
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function(){$(this).attr('url',$(this).attr('url')+'#'+$(this).text())});
});
```

this will turn that link into:

```
<li><a href="contact#Email">Email</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes, my function does exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: So I have one quick question. Does this mean in the end, it is unavoidable to litter my page with dozens of ids?

Comment: There are no ids involved in the solution I provided.

Comment: Can you iterate a bit more on how to use the second function you provided? because what if what was inside my <a> was a whole sentence?

Comment: Rather than typing out hashes for every link, e.g., `<li><a href="contact#email">Email</a></li>`, you can do this automatically based on the content of the link text.

Answer (score 0):

Just do...

```
<li><a href="contact#email">Email</a></li>
<li><a href="contact#onsite">On Site</a></li>
<li><a href="contact#social">Social Media</a></li>
```

Then set the anchors on the page youre talking about

Like so....

```
//email section to link to
 <div id="email"></div>
//onsite section to link to
 <div id="onsite"></div>
```

Comment: The point of the question is that they don't want to litter the page with dozens on ids. I assume it's a FAQ page which can potentially have several dozen questions.

Comment: This was the last resort option I was talking about. What I'm trying to find out is if there is a way to do this without using id's because I'm trying not to have #someid in the address bar.

This is as Joe has mentioned. I do not what to litter my page with several dozen of ids.

Comment: Well the content will be in the divs anyways.....you're not adding anything, you're just referencing where the content is.....this isnt the same as the old way of setting <a name="yournam"></a>  that would be littering....this is just referencing

Comment: You have to have #someid in the address bar if you want to do this......the only other way would be to store the pixel offsets as data attributes in the link, then read those and pass them to javascript.....but still....you will be passing something in the url